# Can I use same name for get and post method in a controller in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Is that possible to use same name for get and post method in a controller in laravel?

```
//in route 
Route::get('form','OrderController@formOrder');
Route::post('form','OrderController@formOrder');

// in controller
[get]
public function formOrder()
{
   //do something
}

[post]
public function formOrder()
{
   //do something else
}
```

something like that..

Comment: [Here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/165467/why-php-doesnt-support-function-overloading) a good answer for method overloading in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
public function formOrder(Request $request)
{
   if($request->isMethod('post')){
         //post data
   }

   if($request->isMethod('get')){
        //get data
   }
}
```

```php
public function formOrder(Request $request)
{
   $method = $request->method();
   if($method == 'post'){
         //post data
   }

   if($method == 'get'){
        //get data
   }
}
```

you can also make single route

```php
Route::match(['get', 'post'], 'form','OrderController@formOrder');
```

Comment: Method names are with capital letters, so the correct way is: $method = $request->method();
        if($method == 'POST'){..}   if($method == 'GET'){..}

Comment: as we are using a comparison operator not  identity operator so that's why its work fine.